# Что делает данная команда

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Не могу понять что делает данная команда

```
public IEnumerable<Car> Cars => DBcontent.Car.Include(c=>c.Category);
```

Сам класс Car

```
  public class Car
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string shortDesc { get; set; }
        public string longDesc { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public ushort price { set; get; }
        public bool isFavourate { set; get; }
        public bool available { set; get; }
        public int CategoryID { set; get; }
        public virtual Category Category { set; get; }  
    }
```

Comment: Включает в запрос загрузку категории для машины, по умолчанию в запрос попадает только машина

Comment: Как и сказал こきん, подробнее можно узнать тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php